# Create a list from a ziped list only considering the elements of other list

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list from a ziped list (ziped_list) but only considering the elements of another list (other).

The two base lists are:

```py
base1 = [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],
         ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B', 'C']]
base2 = [[1.0, 5.0], [3.0], [2.0, 7.0, 3.0, 1.0, 6.0], [3.0], [5.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0], [9.0, 3.0], [2.0, 7.0],
              [3.0, 6.0, 8.0], [2.0], [7.0, 9.0]]
```

- The ziped list is created as follows:

```py
ziped_list = list(zip(base1, base2))
```

Which looks like this:

```py
[(['A', 'B'], [1.0, 5.0]),
 (['B'], [3.0]),
 (['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [2.0, 7.0, 3.0, 1.0, 6.0]),
 (['B'], [3.0]),
 (['A', 'B', 'C'], [5.0, 2.0, 3.0]),
 (['A'], [1.0]),
 (['B', 'C'], [9.0, 3.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [2.0, 7.0]),
 (['C', 'A', 'B'], [3.0, 6.0, 8.0]),
 (['A'], [2.0]),
 (['B', 'C'], [7.0, 9.0])]
```

- The other (reference) list is:

```py
other = ['A', 'B']
```

The expected result is:

```py
[(['A', 'B'], [1.0, 5.0]),
 (['B'], [3.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [2.0, 7.0]),
 (['B'], [3.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [5.0, 2.0]),
 (['A'], [1.0]),
 (['B'], [9.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [2.0, 7.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [6.0, 8.0]),
 (['A'], [2.0]),
 (['B'], [7.0])]
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work as I expected:

```py
otherSet = set(other)
result = [[x for x in arr if x in otherSet] for arr in ziped_list[:][0]]
result
```

If you can elaborate on how to fix my code or find another pythonic way it would be helpful.

Comment: If you can change base1 into a list of tuples you can create a `dictionary` from the zipped result. Then use a `for` loop and check if elements of `other` are part of the key.

Comment: @AnnZen yes thanks!

Comment: May be there is another answer. Your It isnt fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
base1 = [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B', 'C']]
base2 = [[1.0, 5.0], [3.0], [2.0, 7.0, 3.0, 1.0, 6.0], [3.0], [5.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0], [9.0, 3.0], [2.0, 7.0], [3.0, 6.0, 8.0], [2.0], [7.0, 9.0]]
other = ['A', 'B']

lst1 = [[(a,i) for i,a in enumerate(l) if a in other] for l in base1] # List of letters with index
lst2 = [[l[i] for b,i in a] for a,l in zip(lst1,base2)] # List of numbers found by using the indexes in lst1
lst1 = [[s[0] for s in l] for l in lst1] # Remove index from letters

lst = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(lst1, lst2)] # Zip up list of letters and list of numbers

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[(['A', 'B'], [1.0, 5.0]),
 (['B'], [3.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [2.0, 7.0]),
 (['B'], [3.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [5.0, 2.0]),
 (['A'], [1.0]),
 (['B'], [9.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [2.0, 7.0]),
 (['A', 'B'], [6.0, 8.0]),
 (['A'], [2.0]),
 (['B'], [7.0])]
```

#### UPDATE:

Here is how you can use `operator.itemgetter()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter as ig

base1 = [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B', 'C']]
base2 = [[1.0, 5.0], [3.0], [2.0, 7.0, 3.0, 1.0, 6.0], [3.0], [5.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0], [9.0, 3.0], [2.0, 7.0], [3.0, 6.0, 8.0], [2.0], [7.0, 9.0]]
other = ['A', 'B']

idx = [[i for i,a in enumerate(l) if a in other] for l in base1] # Nested list of indexes

lst1 = [ig(*i)(l) for l, i in zip(base1, idx)] # List of letters
lst2 = [ig(*i)(l) for l, i in zip(base2, idx)] # List of numbers

lst = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(lst1, lst2)] # Zip the list of letters and numbers
```

Comment: How large are your lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `zip` again to filter:

```
base1 = [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B', 'C']]
base2 = [[1.0, 5.0], [3.0], [2.0, 7.0, 3.0, 1.0, 6.0], [3.0], [5.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0], [9.0, 3.0], [2.0, 7.0], [3.0, 6.0, 8.0], [2.0], [7.0, 9.0]]
other = ['A', 'B']
result = [list(zip(*[[j,k] for j, k in zip(a, b) if j in other])) for a, b in zip(base1, base2)]
```

Output:

```
[[('A', 'B'), (1.0, 5.0)], 
 [('B',), (3.0,)], 
 [('A', 'B'), (2.0, 7.0)], 
 [('B',), (3.0,)], 
 [('A', 'B'), (5.0, 2.0)], 
 [('A',), (1.0,)], 
 [('B',), (9.0,)], 
 [('A', 'B'), (2.0, 7.0)], 
 [('A', 'B'), (6.0, 8.0)], 
 [('A',), (2.0,)], 
 [('B',), (7.0,)]]
```

Comment: Good, The only problem is that this procedure looks slow.